# Confusion with previous definition errors

Tags: c, struct, graph

I'm doing some graph exercises in C and was confused by the sample solutions. I've attached my code below with additions from the sample solutions I don't understand yet.

My question is why in the `sp_algo` function multiple declaration and initialization of `struct queueNode adjCell;` and `struct Point new_point;` works? On the other hand, if I, for example, declare and initalize `struct Point end = {2, 6};` in the main function twice, it returns an error:

```
previous definition of 'end' was here & redefinition of 'end'.
```

The code is not so important but I'll explain it briefly. The task was to get the shortest path from a starting point to a end point in a maze given by array A. For that I implemented a BFS. There's also an implementation of a Queue which I need in the `sp_algo` in order to implement the BFS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GRIDSIZE 7
#define MAXQSIZE 49

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct queueNode
{
    struct Point pt;  // The cordinates of a cell
    int dist;  // cell's distance of from the source
};

bool isValid(int row, int col)
{
    // return true if row number and column number
    // is in range
    return (row >= 0) && (row < GRIDSIZE) &&
           (col >= 0) && (col < GRIDSIZE);
}

struct queueNode queue[MAXQSIZE]; //initialize QUEUE

int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
int size = -1;

bool q_isempty()
{
    return size < 0;
}

void q_enqueue(struct queueNode value)
{
    if(size<MAXQSIZE)
    {
        if(size<0)
        {
            queue[0] = value;
            front = rear = 0;
            size = 1;
        }
        else if(rear == MAXQSIZE-1)
        {
            queue[0] = value;
            rear = 0;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            queue[rear+1] = value;
            rear++;
            size++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue is full\n");
    }
}

int q_dequeue()
{
    if(size<0)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        size--;
        front++;
    }
}

struct queueNode q_front()
{
    return queue[front];
}


////FUNCTION WE NEED TO IMPLEMENT...
int sp_algo(int A[GRIDSIZE][GRIDSIZE], struct Point start, struct Point end){
    int visited[GRIDSIZE][GRIDSIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<GRIDSIZE; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<GRIDSIZE; ++j){
            visited[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    //all 4 directions we can go to (up,down,left,right)
    int row_num[] = {-1, 0, 0, 1};
    int col_num[] = {0, -1, 1, 0};
    
    struct queueNode n1;
    struct queueNode tmp;
    n1.dist = 0;
    n1.pt = start;
    q_enqueue(n1);
    
    while(q_isempty() == false){
        tmp = q_front();
        q_dequeue();
        if(tmp.pt.x == end.x && tmp.pt.y == end.y){ //we found it!!!
            return tmp.dist;
        }
        ///else, search the neighbors!
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
            int new_row = tmp.pt.x + row_num[i];
            int new_col = tmp.pt.y + col_num[i];
            if (isValid(new_row, new_col) == true && visited[new_row][new_col] == -1 && A[new_row][new_col] == '.'){
                        struct queueNode adjCell;
                        struct Point new_point;
                        new_point.x = new_row;
                        new_point.y = new_col;
                        adjCell.dist = tmp.dist+1;
                        adjCell.pt = new_point;
                        visited[new_row][new_col] = 1;
                        q_enqueue(adjCell);     
            }
        }
    }
}




int main() {
  int A[7][7] =
    {
        { '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#'},
        { '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
        { '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.'},
        { '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#'},
        { '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.'},
        { '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '#', '.'},
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    };
  struct Point start = {0, 0};
  struct Point end = {2, 6};

    int spDist = sp_algo(A, start, end);
    printf("It takes a total of %d steps to reach the destination!\n", spDist);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct queueNode adjCell` and `struct Point new_point`are being initialized twice, but not in the same scope.

Eg.

```
{
int a = 5;
printf("%d\n", a); //The scope of a is limited to the {} braces,
}                  //meaning after the closing brace, a no longer exists

//a doesn't exist here

int a = 2 //This can even be a different data type
printf("%d\n", a);
```

And it prefers local variables(ones whose scope is limited to the current piece of code) over global ones. Eg.

```
int a = 5;
{
    int a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", a); //This prints 3
}
```

Same with the if loops, it behaves the same like:

```
{
    struct Point new_point;
    //Whatever code
}
{
    struct Point new_point;
    //Whatever code
}
{
    struct Point new_point;
    //Whatever code
}
 //On and on for how many loops
```

***NOTE: I'm not saying this is how loops work, I am saying it behaves like this***

...Continues however many times the loop continues. Basically, after one iteration of a loop, it enters a new scope where the previous variables don't exist.

This is what allows you to declare variables inside loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int a; //Even though this code executed 5 times, this doesn't cause problems.
}
```

Most of my explanation is in the comments, so please read those.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know it looks at the loop like a "scope".. I only thought and knew of scopes before in the sense of a function scope or global scope.